# Tags HTML com RegEx

Tags: java, android, regex

É o seguinte, eu o usando a seguinte expressão:

```
<div class="teste">(.+?)</div>
```

E esse é o conteúdo, por ex.:

```
<div class="teste">asdasdad<div>zxczxczxc</div>lkjlkjjlkj</div><div>asdasd</div>
```

Eu gostaria que ele pegasse a div correta, ou seja:

```
<div class="teste">asdasdad<div>zxczxczxc</div>lkjlkjjlkj</div>
```

Mas ele retorna até o primeiro < /div>:

```
<div class="teste">asdasdad<div>zxczxczxc</div>
```

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

OBS: Estou fazendo isso em java (android)

Comment: OBS: Já procurei no GOOGLE, Stack, etc...

Comment: Existe um número limitado de `<div>`'s dentro da `<div class="teste">` ou pode haver N `<div>`'s ?

Comment: [Parsar HTML com regex não é uma boa idéia](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/664577). Você pode fazer isso facilmente e corretamente com [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath), por exemplo: `//div[@class="teste"]`

Answer (score 1):

Que tal

```
var conteudo = document.getElementsByClassName('teste')[0].InnetHtml;
```

Irá retornar todo o conteúdo dentro da div teste.. somente dentro dela.

Ha! Em html5 não existem expressões regulares.

Answer (score 1):

Você deveria transformar o quantificador possessivo (possessive quantifier) `+?` em um quantificador ganancioso (greedy quantifier) `*`

```
<div class="teste">(.*)</div>
```

Isso fará a regex checar até o fim da linha e pegar a ultima ocorrência de `</div>` e incluir todos os caracteres possíveis que não são line breakers (`\n`)

Answer (score 0):

Olá, Marcelo.

Você não explicou claramente o que deseja fazer, mais eu entendi que você tá fazendo uma gambiarra, ficaria mais fácil se você simplificasse o código, aonde fica muita mais fácil usar a lógica.

**Ex:**

`<div class="teste">asdasdad</div> 
 <div class="teste">zdsasfsaf</div>`

Você pode usar uma div já criada, quantas vezes quiser.

**ABS:** Tentei ajudar, pelo o que eu entendi na sua postagem =D